# How to automatically attach images to a post after uploading?

Tags: php, image-processing, editor

I am designing a blogsite where everyone can write blogpost.

I am using ckeditor in the create_post.php but there is a problem:

An user could upload an image through the ckeditor and then could close the create_post.php page. So in this case an image is uploaded on the server but no one will see it because the user close the page before to post it.

Is there a way to a automatically attach images to a post after uploading ?

This is the form:

```
<form method="post" action="create_post.php" >
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="body" ></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="send" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the CKEditor API to insert that image. Check [this demo](http://www.martinezdelizarrondo.com/ckplugins/imagepaste.demo/) it automatically inserts any image that you add through various methods (drag&drop, paste, toolbar button).

But that doesn't solve your problem at all. The user can still close the page and the image will be stored but will not be used, so you should create some system to track that.